# GraphQLErrorFilter Save Error log in Database

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

I'm trying to save to the database all the errors that the error filter get.  This is what i'm trying.

in Startup.cs

```
.AddErrorFilter<GraphQLErrorFilter>(provider =>
           {
               
               return new GraphQLErrorFilter(provider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>());
           })
```

In the Error filter i'm calling the log service as a normal service.

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    //private readonly ILogsService logs;
    public GraphQLErrorFilter(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        //this.logs = logs;
    }
```

Im getting this error message:

No service for type 'XXXXXXXXX.IUnitOfWork' has been registered.'

Comment: IErrorFilter is not meant for logging but for transforming error objects. For error logging use the diagnostic event listeners.

Comment: https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/server/instrumentation